# How to setup DB in postgresql 9.2.4 on 12.04.2 LTS

Tags: 12.04, postgresql

I THINK I have PostgreSQL running correctly on my box: I have a PID and I see that postgres is "listening" on port 5432.

I'm trying to create a DB to experiment with, using the "Book" db outlined in C. Fehily's book "Visual Quickstart SQL".

I've tried a bunch of approaches, but have had no joy. Latest approach is:

```
$ su postgres
Password: 
postgres@piglet:/etc$ createdb books
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
postgres@piglet:/etc$
```

I'm not sure if I'm hitting the wall on passwords or authorizations, or something else. I'd sure welcome some suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You first have to install postgres-xc-client

`sudo apt-get install postgres-xc-client`

and then

`sudo apt-get install postgres-xc`

And then do

`postgres -D <Postgres Data Dir> -X`

This will start the server

And then do

`createdb books`

**NOTE:** I personally think, setting up postgres is very vague or broad question

Comment: @thefourtheye What's this got to do with `postgres-xc`? Looks like regular PostgreSQL to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PostgreSQL is running and listening on port 5432 according to `netstat` but when you run `psql` you get an error like:

```
psql: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

then most likely the issue is that you're using the `psql` from an earlier version of PostgreSQL that's also installed on your system. This version is probably configured to use a different `unix_socket_directory`.

The best option is to set your `PATH` environment variable to point to the directory containing the correct `psql`, `createdb`, etc versions before the old ones.

Alternately, you can use TCP/IP connections by explicitly specifying `-h localhost`, eg:

```
psql -h localhost ...
```

(and thus `createdb -h localhost ...`). This will result in you using old versions of the `createdb`, `psql`, etc commands, so it's better to just set your `PATH`. The same is true of using `-h` to set the unix socket path, which is somewhat of an advanced option.

Fix your `PATH` environment variable and all will be well. You can test this temporarily with something like the following, where you'd replace `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin` with the `bin` directory under your PostgreSQL 9.2 installation:

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH
psql
```

If that works, you'll need to make the change permanent by editing `/etc/environment`, your `.bash_profile`, or other appropriate settings files. Search for "ubuntu permanently set PATH" for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll do some checking with your suggestions. I have a related question, though: I have Postgresql 9.1.x as well as 9.2.4 installed (9.1.x came with the original install, and then I upgraded as recommended on the PostgreSQL.org site)... Would these problems also disappear if I just removed 9.1.x via apt-get remove command string?

Comment: I removed the 9.1 version OK but psql still returns error. I'm working on the $PATH activity now.

Comment: Hi Craig, I tried the command  'export PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin:$PATH'  but received same error message  'psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?'  I'll try the localhost option to see if that works.

Comment: Turns out Postgresql 9.2.4 is listening on port 5433

Comment: I can see the DB now -- there are still some dball config issue to fix, but I'm on the right track. Thanks Craig!